# R Test if object exists and is not null in loop

Tags: r, if-statement, logic

this must be really simple but I am struggling to get the logic right.

I have an object "XXX" that is created within an initial if statement (which is in a loop).

I need to create another if layer below so that:

```
      if( exists("XXX") & !is.null(XXX)) { do stuff } else { do other stuff}
```

However, if "XXX" does not exist, I get an error because the !is.null(XXX) is evaluated.

What's a concise and reasonable way to construct this dual condition?

Comment: Use `&&` rather than `&`, it should [short-circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) the comparison.

Comment: common sense strikes again! this is such an elementary step. thank you.

Comment: Should it be `!is.null(XXX)`; ie look at the object, not a non-empty string?

Comment: I am surprised by this; also assumed R didn't allow short-circuiting. Appears it doesn't on `&` but does on `&&`.

Comment: @RussHyde correct , I am editing